# Problems installing uBuntu from memory stick on 2011 MacBook

Tags: dual-boot, usb

I finally thought that I had installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 successfully on a memory stick on a 2011 MacBook Pro but the installation has been made on the Mac itself not the memory stick. I didn't intend this to happen so I hadn't partitioned the drive. Has Linux  overwritten the OSX?
Thanks for any advice or suggestions anyone might be able to offer.

Comment: If the OS was installed on the main disk and you chose to use the entire disk, then OS X is gone and you will need to reinstall 

Comment: My worst nightmare is that it has been installed on my MacBook, the letters of my user name are garbled and I managed to get my log in password wrong! The final blow is I now cannot shut down the Mac! Please  H E L P

Comment: It is difficult to offer assistance when I don’t know what you want to do. Do you wish to re-install OS X?

Comment: Yes I need to restore the Mac OS and start again running the Linux from the external drive which I had done earlier. Ubuntu was only installed on the memory stick so I have no idea how it installed on the Mac without any warning.

Comment: Having used Ubuntu for 15+ years and installing it hundreds of times, I can safely say that there *is* warning. However, it requires a good deal of attention to be paid. We've all accidentally wiped a primary hard drive by accident. Reinstalling OS X is off topic for this site, but [Apple has a page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904) that will explain when to hit ⌘+R to enter into the recovery menu to reinstall the OS.

Comment: Thanks Matigo. All in life's rich experiences I guess. Now I'm battling with the peculiarities of a ten + year old OSX and download a more recent version.